# How to get media count using IG Business Discovery API without permission from 3rd parties?

Tags: instagram, instagram-graph-api

[image: Error code provided by FB in supplement to my most recent comment]

I'm setting up an app that will be able to see if Instagram profiles have been recently active (within 24hrs) by reading the number of "media count" of a specified user.
IG docs are not clear - and their API registration is even less clear on the issue I am facing. My question is, do I need permission (token) from every account that I am trying to pull this data from? If not, what permissions do I need to grant from their Developer site in order to accomplish this?
IG's docs show that permission is needed, but sites like socialblade.com and igblade.com clearly are using their API to gather this data on a large scale basis.

Comment: please add what you tried so far. after checking out the docs, do some testing/programming. btw, wouldn´t it be better to check for the last media entries instead of just the count? the first time you get the count, you don´t know the active status. also, users could delete entries, so the count may not be a good indicator.

Comment: btw, please be careful with tags, the "api" tag clearly says: "DO NOT USE: Tag with the library you mean, [api-design], or something else appropriate instead". i fixed the tags.

Comment: Thanks luschn, as you can tell I'm new here - this helps. I am going to work with my team to try out some testing/programming. I have mainly just been confused as to what we are able to try because their docs are very confusing. And yes, you're right, 'last media entries' would be better, but I don't believe that Instagram API gives that information (something that I could actually understand from their docs) - let me know if I'm wrong on that.

Comment: you are definitely wrong about that, i can tell you for sure that it is possible, even with the new api. if some parts of the docs are confusing, just add them to your question so we know which ones you don´t understand.

Comment: @luschn, our issue was getting "Business Verification". Now that we've got Verified, we're still having issues getting Media_Count.  I tried to do the sample business_discovery api call on the graph api explorer
GET /v3.2/17841405309211844?fields=business_discovery.username(bluebottle){followers_count,media_count}
I’m getting the following response
{
 “error”: {
   “message”: “A user access token is required to request this resource.“,
   “type”: “OAuthException”,
   “code”: 102,
   “fbtrace_id”: “AOwTWc4kcFr”
 }
}
However I'm getting an error when trying to get user access token

Comment: @luschn Are there particular permissions that we need to be approved for in order to get this media_count?

Comment: "i´m getting an error when trying to get user access token" - so what error exactly do you get? of course everything else will not work if you don´t even get a token. that´s pretty much the most obvious and important rule: if you get an error, include the exact error message. always.

Comment: @luschn apologies, I included a screenshot of the error by editing the post but I now see how that would be hard for you to see it.
The exact error was: Invalid scopes: manage_pages . This message is only shown to developers, Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read documentation for valid permissions. 
This brings me to my recent question - in order to get this information that we need (Media count, last media entries), do we just need 'Manage pages'? Or are there other permissions we have to be approved for from Facebook?

Comment: yeah, you should not add linked screenshots for stuff you could just write as a text. makes searching easier too, if it´s in the database ;) - anyway, try with an app user (admin, developer, tester) instead. and try with an app token first.

Comment: @luschn, I really appreciate your help here. However we tried that. I feel like this back and forth in the stackoverflow comments isn't helping much at all, and we just got rejected from FB review and have no idea how to get this to work. Do you have anywhere I could message you quickly about this to clear up the situation? I would really appreciate your time :)

Comment: Hi @luschn, we are still having issues here. Could really use your help if you can spare a few moments. We are very confused as to how to get the data we need without being yet approved for manage_pages. Please let me know if you are able to assist. My email is matt.hakims@gmail.com. Thanks so much